# XML to Dictionary using Linq - Not getting Child values

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Here is my test XML

```
<Customer>
  <CustomerId>123456</CustomerId>
  <CustomerName>ERA01SB17 0101</CustomerName>
 <Address>
    <AddressLine>9955 Rough Rd</AddressLine>
    <City>ST LOUIS</City>
    <County>KING</County>
    <StateOrProvince>MO</StateOrProvince>
    <Country>US</Country>
    <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
 </Address>
 <Contact>
 <PersonName>
    <GivenName>Jim Johnson</GivenName>
    <FamilyName/>
</PersonName>
</Contact>
</Customer
```

Here is my Code in VB.NET

```
Dim dictionaryOut = doc.Root.Elements().ToDictionary(Function(e) e.Name.LocalName, Function(e) e.Value)
```

The output has the Children of Address concatenated together

```
Address, 9955 Rough RdST LOUISKINGMOUS12345
```

How can I get all Children with the Field names and values ?

Thank you

Comment: Looks useful - could you add the code that defines and loads `doc`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change to the code to show all Children:

```
Dim dictionaryOut = doc.Decendants.ToDictionary(Function(e) e.Name.LocalName, Function(e) e.Value)
```